# Memory issue with parameters saved in contexts

Tags: memory, parameters, dialogflow-es, context-switch

I'm currently building a fairly long flow, where I collect quantitative and qualitative input and save it in output contexts with a long lifespan (500 turns).

By the end of the flow, the bot sums up all the answers saved in the parameters my using the
`#outputcontext.parametername` syntax.

This seems to work 50 % of the time. Sometimes, especially if there's been a few fallbacks/repromps during the flow, it won't parse the stored value into the `#outputcontext.parametername` placeholder, but instead just parse the #outputcontext.parametername. I find this odd, as the parameter should still be saved in the context, and I suspect it might have something to do with memory capacity in DF itself, when too many parameters are stored at once.

Have anyone experienced similar issues, and/or found a solution?

Thanks - appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by *"Parsing just the #outputcontext.parametername?"*. Also, have you got any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Dialogflow context saved for 25min then it will be reseted you need to use cloud functions ( fulfillment )